# How to assign each post to an unique id in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to structure my website in this format where there are 2 tables. Table 1 is used to store ids, names and logo for each university. Table 2 is used to store degrees for each university (1 university will have 30 degrees).

The goal here is to create multiple unique posts which can reference data from table 1 and table 2. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Posts already have unique IDs by default in WordPress...

Comment: How can I create multiple posts which are able to reference data from table 1 and table 2?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your use case...but you may be able to use hierarchical posts (child pages), or use a custom meta field to link the posts together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming schools are a post type and degrees are a post type the connecting factor is the school id. You could either do this using custom meta data and add a field (school id etc) to each post type. Or you could create a taxonomy that is shared by both post types that refers to the school id.

You would then be able to use custom queries to get degrees where the school id equals the value you need.

For custom meta:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

For taxonomies:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, Simon. I`ll give it a try and update this post as I go.